# Kubernetes pods failing using deployments, where as my docker run is getting success using proxy configurations

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

***Why is my docker run success and k8s fails to take the proxies***

My Docker container runs by executing a docker run. Where as during my container boots it executes my rest api call under the Spring boot API instance before it get get started in a specfic port.

During the API call it requires a proxy to bypass and access the endpoint, and load all my property details.

Where as i am getting is happened when i run it using the docker run.
But fails when the same is ran under kubernetes.

*Logs on failure*

```
2020-08-13 07:26:21.096 ERROR 1 --- [           main] c.e.f.utils.config.FSFConfigRestClient   : Could not connect to iConfig after 3 retries
2020-08-13 07:26:21.101 ERROR 1 --- [           main] c.e.f.utils.config.FSFConfigRestClient   : Error occured while fetching configurations from e-config service @ http://jconfig.ezpaas-nonprod.***.com/econfig/
```

due to I/O error on POST request for "http://jconfig.ezpaas-nonprod.***.com/econfig/public/rest-less-api/query-configurations"

### Below is my Docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://http.proxy.abc.com:8000"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "http://http.proxy.abc.com:8000"
ENV NO_PROXY "localhost,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,10.0.0.0/8,192.168.10.0/24,example.com"
MAINTAINER @@@@@@ ***@***.com
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=/daas-service.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dezpaas.config.tenantName=WI_MID_TIER -Dezpaas.config.categories=WI_DCDST:WI_ESTDS:TDS:DEV -jar /app.jar $my_params"]
```

### Below is my Docker Run which is success

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped \
  -p 80:80 \
  -e HTTP_PROXY="http://http.proxy.abc.com:8000" \
  -e HTTPS_PROXY="http://http.proxy.abc.com:8000" \
  -e NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,10.0.0.0/8,192.168.10.0/24,example.com" \
  docker.abc.com/abc-ap119038/daas-service:0.0.1
```

### Below is my deployment which is failing

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: daas-service
  namespace: com-abc-tds-dev
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: daas-service
  template:
    metadata:
      name:
      labels:
        app: daas-service
    spec:
      nodeName: kmaster
      containers:
      - name: daas-service
        image: docker.abc.com/abc-ap119038/daas-service:0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: "HTTP_PROXY"
          value: "http://http.proxy.abc.com:8000"
        - name: "HTTPS_PROXY"
          value: "http://http.proxy.abc.com:8000"
        - name: "NO_PROXY"
          value: "localhost,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,10.0.0.0/8,192.168.10.0/24,example.com"
```

Am i missing out something here. Still wondering how my docker run is success and deployments fail in k8s

Comment: Just as a side note. You are comparing the running of a container to the running of a deployment, but this is not comparable to each other. A container can be compared to a pod, and a deployment is what is known in docker as a service.

Comment: Can you exec into the pod and check the env if proxy is set

Comment: @DanielJacob yes crt. my pods here are failing to come up.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu i could'nt do it, before my pod comes up it keeps on restarting

Comment: Doesn't that mean that your pod.yaml is wrong?

Comment: try do deploy your pod as a single one with kubectl create -f pod.yaml

Comment: @DanielJacob i have made a validation on the yml file which still works fine, and on proxies also get applied under the k8s view when the container comes up

Comment: @DanielJacob resulting the same when i run a single pod.    c.e.f.c.autoconfigure.FSFConfigLocator   : Could not get configuration from iConfig : I/O error on POST request for

Comment: @Ravi as long as you have proxy in docker file it will be set in the pod. I think it's not an issue of setting proxy in pod. Try setting proxy in the Kubernetes node VMs

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yep. point to take, but again my kubernetes node i restricted it to master only deployment as kmaster, which still holds the proxy set available.

Comment: Have you tried running  $ export http_proxy=...
$ export https_proxy=...
$ export NO_PROXY=...  commands directly from the node ?

Comment: @MaggieO to set the node level proxy right? its been set to http://http.proxy.abc.com:8000, i have just printed it.  echo "$https_proxy"
http://http.proxy.abc.com:8000

Answer (score 0):

You have to untaint the master so you can run pods. Execute following command:

```
$ kubectl taint nodes kmaster node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Take a look: [single-node-kubernetes-setup](https://www.redpill-linpro.com/techblog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-setup.html).

Comment: Can you please let me know if it helped ?

Comment: it dosent help.